# Convenient transform of JavaScript method call into function

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to convert a field access or method call into a function that could be passed into e.g. `Array.map`?

```js
a = {'foo': 1};
b = {'foo': 2};
c = {'foo': 3};

[a, b, c].map(m => m.foo);
```

Is `m => m.foo` the best we can do (w/ built-in JS functionality)? Or is there an even shorter way?

Comment: Write readable and well-formatted code. If you have the need to reduce the size/length then use a specialized tool ([js minifier](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20minifier)) for that task.

Answer (score 0):

One more

```
[a, b, c].map(({foo}) => foo)
```

Comment: That's definitely not shorter

Comment: It's maximum :D